# Equivalent letter for H in Russian?

Tags: узус, транслитерация, буквы

I want to pronounce and write the word 'Hindustan'. What is the Russian equivalent for the English letter 'H'?

---

FYI: I am just taking my first steps in learning Russian.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Russian has no special letter for the Latin letter `H`; in other words, it's rendered differently. You have to consult a dictionary every time a proper name has an `H` in it. The most common ways to transcribe it are:

- `Г`: *Гималаи* "the Himalayas", *Генри* "Henry";
- `Х`: *хинди*, *хиндустани* "Hindi, Hindustani (languages)", *Хайдарабад* "Hyderabad";
- `no letter at all`: *Индостан* "Hindustan (subcontinent)".