# Why "Гиппократ" but "ипподром"?

Tags: этимология, правописание

Both these words have Greek origin, specifically:

**Гиппократ** (Hippocrates) comes from *ίππος* (horse) + *κρατώ* (I hold) = The one who holds the horses.

**Ипподром** (horse-race track) comes from *ίππος* (horse) + *δρόμος* (road/track).

The word for horse, in original (polytonic) Greek is written as

> ἵππος

where over the *ι* there is an ascent and an aspirate: 
[image]

The aspirate is the one that means an "h" has to be added in English to convey the original Greek sound (therefore "**H**ippocrates" in English.)

In Russian this (thick) "h" is turned into a "**Г**" (e.g. **H**amburger - **Г**амбургер).

Why this is not the case with **Ипподром**?

Comment: Russian has been gradually moving from Church Slavonic tradition of transliteration according to Byzantine pronunciation into the modern one using Ancient Greek pronunciation, see here: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/219/are-there-words-that-can-be-spelled-with-both-%D1%82-and-%D1%84/221#221

Comment: See also http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14000/equivalent-word-for-h-in-russian

Comment: I think the best way to write it is Russian would be йиппо-

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The word "гипподром" is [still used](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) as a historical term for ancient stadiums for horse racing. The reason for dropping "г" was French influence where "h" is not pronounced (and the word [hippodrome](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippodrome) is not an exception). French was heavily used by Russian aristocracy and actually a lot of words were borrowed in French spelling. Even English names, like Ньютон were stressed the way they are stressed in French.

Here's a screenshot of N-gram for usage of both гипподром and ипподром (both in old and new spelling)

[image]

One can answer - why in that case Гиппократ, not Иппократ? Behold the terrifying truth, it actually was that way:

[image]

So actually Г-форм gained popularity gradually, throughout 19th century.

To me this looks like more or less random, the same Greek root gave us `гиппопотам` which, to my knowledge, never has been spelled without `г-`.